# Turn off query statistics window every time I run a query

Tags: sql-server, statistics

Every time I run a query, this pops up:

[image]

How do I turn this off?

Comment: Execute: `SET STATISTICS PROFILE OFF;`

Comment: Query-->Query Options-->Execution-->Advanced--> uncheck SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT